# Unable to build and run Gollum gem with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv, gollum-wiki

I wish to run the development version of Gollum on an Ubuntu 14.04 server using rbenv to manage the ruby and gem versions. I have used the following commands to build and install gollum. If I use `rbenv shell system` first to bypass rbenv then I am able to build and run correctly.

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p551
rbenv rehash
git clone git@github.com:gollum/gollum.git
cd gollum
rbenv local 1.9.3-p551
gem install bundle
rbenv rehash
bundle install
rake build
gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc pkg/gollum-4.0.0.gem
```

Then running `gollum` results in the following error:

```
[dkozel@server gollum] gollum
/home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:204: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I have tried clean installing the ruby version and all gems, installing the gems in vendor/bundle, building different release tags of Gollum, and using Ruby 2.2.2 instead of 1.9.3p551.

Running the gem from `~/gollum/bin` with extra debug flags produces this full trace.

```
[dkozel@server bin] ruby -wdS gollum
Exception `LoadError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1264 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1273 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Exception `LoadError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists - /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203f7f8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203f140>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203ec40>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203e538>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203de80>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="rack" requirements=">= 1.0">:Gem::Dependency
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002061b00>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x000000020613f8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="ansi" requirements=">= 0">:Gem::Dependency
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002052c40>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002052718>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002052100>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="json" requirements=">= 0">:Gem::Dependency
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="tzinfo" requirements=">= 0">:Gem::Dependency
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x000000020516d8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000204cae8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000204c638>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000204c188>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000204bcd8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000204b828>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000204b378>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="rack" requirements="~> 1.4">:Gem::Dependency
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000205f558>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000205f058>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000205a738>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000205a288>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002057790>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002060390>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002042ac0>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002050300>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="rack" requirements=">= 0">:Gem::Dependency
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203cf08>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203c850>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x0000000203c3a0>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002046918>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002046468>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x000000020442a8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002043df8>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002043948>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb:39 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x00000002043498>
Exception `SystemStackError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:111 - stack level too deep
Exception `SystemStackError' at /home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:204 - stack level too deep
/home/dkozel/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:204: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Comment: Seems your having dependency issues. Since you're using bundler, why not create a Gemfile and add it there, then bundle it -- that way bundler should handle it. Also, this way you don't have to build from source.

Comment: Gollum comes with a Gemfile and I'm using bundle install as mentioned above. The issue is with my use of rbenv to manage ruby environments. I can build correctly using the system ruby. I wish to build form source to see some of the development changes made since the latest stable release.

Comment: Try running `rbenv install 1.9.3-p551` and `rbenv local 1.9.3-p551` and then finally `rbenv rehash`. You didn't include the `-` in the version -- mine throws an error for that, not sure why yours does not. And you should rehash after setting local.

Comment: It did throw an error and I used the dash'd version. The question had a typo, well spotted though! I will try the additional rehash now, thanks!